# Tensorflow fails to initialize batch normalization layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm running Tensorflow 1.12 on GPU in a conda environment. I have several batch norm layers as part of convolution blocks defined in this way:

```
Conv=lambda NumFilter, Input, FilterSize=PARAMS['FilterSize'] : tf.layers.conv2d(Input, NumFilter, FilterSize, strides=1, activation=None, padding='SAME', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=PARAMS['KernelInit'])

def OneConv(layer,FilterNum,FilterSize,training):
    activate=tf.nn.relu(layer)
    norm=tf.layers.batch_normalization(activate,axis=-1,training=training)
    conv=Conv(FilterNum,norm,FilterSize)
    return conv

def ConvBlock(BlockInput,name, FilterNum, training):
    with tf.name_scope(name):

        conv1=OneConv(BlockInput,FilterNum,PARAMS['FilterSize'],training)
        conc1=tf.concat([BlockInput,conv1],axis=-1)

        conv2=OneConv(conc1,FilterNum,PARAMS['FilterSize'],training)
        conc2=tf.concat([BlockInput,conv1,conv2],axis=-1)

        BlockOut=OneConv(conc2,FilterNum,1,training)

        return BlockOut
```

Which I use to build the Forward function. Whenever I try to test the network with:

```
X=tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1,128,128,1),dtype=tf.float32)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
test=Forward(X)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(test.eval())
```

I get an error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value BatchNorm_12/beta
>        [[node BatchNorm_12/beta/read (defined at /home/riccardo/.anaconda3/envs/Tenso/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py:277)  = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]
>        [[{{node ConvBlockUp1_1/conv2d_2/BiasAdd/_7}} = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_520_ConvBlockUp1_1/conv2d_2/BiasAdd", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I can't quite figure out why the global initializer fails to initialize the batch norm layers, I also tried passing on specific initializers for the batchnorm parameters to tf.layers.batch_normalization but it did not change anything. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the variables initializer *after* you have created your model. Try:

```
X=tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1,128,128,1),dtype=tf.float32)

test=Forward(X)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(test.eval())
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks! I wasn't even looking for something that simple.